# How can I fix this DetailedApiRequestError(status: 404, message: No error details. HTTP status was: 404.)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api

anybody knows what I'm doing wrong, I keep getting this error

```
DetailedApiRequestError(status: 404, message: No error details. HTTP status was: 404.)
```

Here's my code.

```
final _credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(r'''
  {
    "private_key_id": "4XXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
    "private_key": ".....==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "xxxxxxx@----.com",
    "client_id": "11XXXXXXXXXXXXXX4",
    "type": "service_account"
  }
  ''');

clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _SCOPES).then((http_client) {
      var pubSubClient = new PubsubApi(http_client);

      var messages = {
        'messages': [
          {
            'data': base64Encode(utf8.encode('{"foo": "bar"}')),
          },
        ]
      };



      pubSubClient.projects.topics
          .publish(new PublishRequest.fromJson(messages), "your-topic")
          .then((publishResponse) {
        debugPrint(publishResponse.toString());
      }).catchError((e,m){
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      });
    });
```

I have a stateful widget with this code in `initState()`, when I run it I get the error above. when I check my google cloud nothing is published. Anyone who can help me quickly.

Answer (score 0):

So this here a solution, change this:

```
pubSubClient.projects.topics
          .publish(new PublishRequest.fromJson(messages), "your-topic")
          .then((publishResponse) {
        debugPrint(publishResponse.toString());
      }).catchError((e,m){
        print(m.toString());
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      });
```

to this:

```
    pubSubClient.projects.topics
          .publish(new PublishRequest.fromJson(messages), "projects/projectIDXX/topics/yourTopic")
          .then((publishResponse) {
        debugPrint(publishResponse.toString());
      }).catchError((e,m){
        print(m.toString());
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      });
```

The issue was with topic.